# extend a user profile in django to include profile photo

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I am trying to extend a user profile in django so that user can add profile photo and birthday date and I am using django-allauth for my user authentication. I am currently following a reference but for the reference a new user registration was used without involving django-allauth. I have thus implemented the codes but stock on one point where I can not figure out where to place this particular line of code

```
# Create the user profile
profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)
```

below is the profile Edit code
**Model**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(
            upload_to= upload_location,
            null = True,
            blank = True,
            height_field = "height_field",
            width_field = "width_field")

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Profile for user {}'.format(self.user.username)
```

**Form.py**

```
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email']

class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """docstring for ProfileEditForm."""
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['date_of_birth', 'photo']
```

**View**

```
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance = request.user, data = request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance = request.user.profile, data = request.POST, files = request.FILES)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()

    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance= request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)

   return render(request, 'account/edit.html',
    {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
```

and if I try to run the code like that I get an error `User has no profile.` any further code would be presented based on request.

**Urls**

```
url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit, name='update_profile'),
```

**Template**

```
<form method="POST" action="." class="" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {{ profile_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update">

</form>
```

Comment: add `urls.py` as well as `template`.

Comment: you just need to make a profile for each user?right? you can use signals to add a profile for each user when a new user has been created.

Comment: I have included it @PiyushMaurya

Comment: @Navid2zp I want users to be able to edit their profile to upload a photo since no photo upload when registering

Comment: did you take care of making a profile for each user? and the only problem is uploading photo? or you need to do everything including creating a profile for each user which include few field like avatar and ... ?

Comment: add `return` statement after `profile_form.save()`, something like `return HttpResponseRedirect() #add your own redirect view`.

Comment: @Navid2zp has it, you can add a signal handler to save a profile when a new user is created. Another option, you can monkey-patch the `User` object with a property that will fetch the profile if it exists, or create it if it does not, then use that property to load the profile in the rest of your code.

Comment: @Navid2zp  user can sign up. that means creating an account. using django-allauth I then want to extend the ready created account to be able to create a profile which would contain users initial details with ability to alter those details (email, username, ...) and also add new fields like profile photo and birthday date

Comment: @PiyushMaurya that still does not solve the problem as it would reqire ` User has no profile. `

Comment: i don't think you really need django-allauth to do that, you can simply do it yourself. but the problem here is that the user has no profile. like @wmorrell mentioned you can check if the profile exist and if not create one and then try to save the data. check this out too: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820931)

Comment: @Navid2zp I used django-allauth for my user authentication

Comment: @King can you see the profile for that user in your admin panel? or profile isn't even there?

Comment: the main problem is this `profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user)` which I don't know where to position it

Comment: when you register a new user, and after you saved the new user. you can put it after you saved the user and user=your-new-user-instance

Comment: @Navid2zp I can see it in the admin panel but using it in my template i get an error  saying `User has no profile.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, add (or add elsewhere, and import):

```
def load_profile(user):
  try:
    return user.profile
  except:  # this is not great, but trying to keep it simple
    profile = Profile.objects.create(user=user)
    return profile
```

Then change your view function to use `load_profile(request.user)` instead of `request.user.profile`.

**View**

```
def edit(request):
    profile = load_profile(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(
            instance=request.user,
            data=request.POST,
        )
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(
            instance=profile,
            data=request.POST,
            files=request.FILES,
        )

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()

    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=profile)

    return render(
        request,
        'account/edit.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form}
    )
```

Comment: sorry I am confused

Comment: Your problem is there is no `profile` attribute on `user`. This function takes a `user` object, and tries to return the `profile`. If one does not exist (the error you are seeing), then a `DoesNotExist` exception is thrown. The function catches that exception, then creates a new profile to attach to the user, and returns that new profile.

Comment: okay. I understand your explanation but could you help edit your answer to include my view?

Comment: Ok, but it's literally just replacing `request.user.profile` with the result of calling `load_profile(request.user)` just like I said.

Comment: I have actually done that but the problem now is that it is not creating the profile

Comment: I got the error `Reverse for 'profiles' not found. 'profiles' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: You will need to be more specific. `load_profile` will either return a profile that exists or return a brand new profile. What is the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: it was a typo graphical error it should be profile. thanks.

Comment: I have marked it has correct. any chance of chatting with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152664/discussion-between-wmorrell-and-king).

Comment: Hi I need you help regarding a question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263867/creating-relationship-between-two-apps-in-django

Answer (score 1):

As your error tells User profile doesn't exist:
In your `view`:

```
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if profile_form.is_valid():
            instance = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return # add here

    else:
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm()

    return render(request, 'account/edit.html', {'profile_form': profile_form})
```

It will work.

Comment: I haven't included `user_form` because error is caused by `profile_form`.

Comment: Kindly include it beacase I have not seen any where with profiles please

Comment: Just use it and check if photo is updating/uploading.

Comment: the form is not showing on the template. it is not loading up but there are no errors

Comment: in `template`, use only `{{ profile_form.as_p }}` and then check. Remove `{{ user_form.as_p }}` just for testing, once it worked, you can add it later.

Comment: I got this error after I submitted the form `super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152660/discussion-between-piyush-maurya-and-king).

Comment: Hi I need you help regarding a question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263867/creating-relationship-between-two-apps-in-django